# Updating a pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a pivot table

```
id | product_id | user_id
```

I wish to update this pivot table, I do so by:

```
Product::find($productId)->attach($userId);
```

This will produce something like

```
id | product_id | user_id
 1        1          1
```

But then when I do it again I do not want to update the pivot table if the values already exists.

The above attach method would do something like:

```
id | product_id | user_id
 1        1          1
 1        1          1
```

I know you can use sync, but this removes everything from the table, I do not wish to do this. I also know you can use:

```
Product::find(1)->user()->updateExistingPivot(1, []);
```

But this only works when data is in the table.

What Im looking for is a way to do firstOrCreate on a pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a boolean to your sync method which just adds the value and doesn't remove the existing value.

The code looks like this. The first value can be an int or array.

```
Product::find(1)->user()->sync([1], false);
```